# Can't get preg_replace to remove some numbers

Tags: php, xml, regex, preg-replace

I have a String that I have extracted using the `__getLastResponse` function on a `SoapClient` object from a Web Service.

This string is in the format of an XML document except that it has some unnecessary digits at the start which I need to remove before I can parse it as XML.

I have written a `preg_replace` function to remove these numbers but it isn't working; could anyone please explain why?

Here's the relevant code:

```
$string = $search_client->__getLastResponse();

$string = preg_replace('/\A^\d+\', '', $string);
```

The initial String starts like `234682374643<records xmlns="http://scien...</records>` etc. and I am trying to get `<records xmlns="http://scien...</records>`.

Thanks for your help.

**** ADDITIONAL 1 ****

If I enter `$string = preg_replace("/\d+/", "", $string);` then it removes ALL the digits from the String so I know that everything else is working correctly, just the pattern that isn't for some reason (I don't want to remove the other digits, just the first ones).

**** ADDITIONAL 2 ****

Here is the `$search_response` stdClass object which is a `print_r` of the initiated Soap Client object with the `search($params)` function called upon it:

```
stdClass Object
(
[return] => stdClass Object
    (
        [queryId] => 1
        [recordsFound] => 3670
        [recordsSearched] => 38802522
        [records] => 
WOS:A1993LC481000015-&BRESINSKY, ABRESINSKY,... etc ...
    )
)
```

As you can see the String I'm extracting from `__getLastResponse` includes all the values as one String with the numbers '1367038802522' followed by the 'records' values. It is these numbers that I'm trying to get rid of because I believe I will then be able to parse the remaining String as XML, perhaps by using SimpleXmlElement.

Comment: Where is the modifiers? Why you used `^` between the patterns?

Comment: You have written a backslash instead of a slash at the end of the pattern. Remove the `^` that is redondant with `\A`.

Comment: Don't you have some spaces before the digits?

Comment: Don't think so, can't see any whitespace when I do a var_dump. Can I do a `trim(preg_replace('/^\d+/', "", $string));` to ensure any whitespace is removed though?

Comment: sorry, probably `ltrim` rather than `trim`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`\A`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) and [`^`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) do the same (start of subject), similar to `\Z` and `$` (end of subject).

Having both `\A` and `^` breaks the match.

Your delimiters are also off.

Try:

```
$string = "123foo";
$string = preg_replace('/^\d+/', '', $string);
var_dump($string); // "foo"
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. It still won't work even when I remove the `\A` however.

Comment: If it doesn't work the problem might be elsewhere, maybe your input is not what you think it is. I added sample code that I tested.

Comment: Hmm, yes tested that and it comes out correctly as "foo". Thanks, I'll look further and see if I can figure out how my input is not as I thought!

Comment: Found out why but rather than post it here I added it as another answer to explain why it wasn't working. Input wasn't as expected as you pointed out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `^` after `\A`. Use it like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\A\d+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Can you show output of `var_dump($search_client->__getLastResponse());`

Comment: It's pretty huge so I'll miss out the middle section but here's out it starts: `string(31717) "1367038802522<records xmlns="http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/...` and how it ends: `...</identifiers></cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC> </records>`

Answer (score 1):

Try it again after removing `\A`

```
$re = "/^\\d+/";
$str = "234682374643<records xmlns=\"http://scien...</records>";
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Look at [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dK6qF7/3)

Comment: Thanks, still no change when I do this though! I tested the `^\d+` in an online regex tester too and it works there, not sure why it isn't working on the string in my code.  Why does it need the extra slashes at the start and end of the pattern? Also, what is the extra slash after `^` for? Thanks

Comment: the extra slash is used to escape `\` of `\d`. Try the code that I shared you and let me know whether the above mentioned code is working for you or not. Can you try `$re = "/\\d+(?=<)/";` just for testing of your string.

Comment: Have done a test based on the short code snippet Halcyon provided which works as it should so think that my input must not be as I thought. I'll have a look and see what's going on with my input, thanks!

Comment: Found out why it wasn't working and have posted the reason in an answer. There was some hidden data at the start of the string hence the confusion. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.

Discovered why this was happening when I ran the test that Halcyon posted and he suggested that the input may not be as I thought. It turns out that whenever I `print_r` or `var_dump` or whatever the `__getLastResponse` it was just displaying the values and missing out a bunch of tags that appeared before the string, namely:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:searchResponse xmlns:ns2="http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com"><return><queryId>1</queryId><recordsFound>3670</recordsFound><recordsSearched>38802522</recordsSearched><records>... etc...</records>
```

This is what was actually returned as opposed to the `1367038802522` prefix that was displayed. As you can see these numbers are all the values within the tags above. I got this output by applying `htmlspecialchars($search_client->__getLastResponse());` to show these previously 'hidden' fields.

What's weird though and I'm not sure why it's doing this is that everything is displayed correctly until after the `<records>` tag, after which all opening tags (`<`) are displayed as `&lt;`. So before the `<records>` tag it displays `<` correctly and after this it displays `&lt;` instead!

Comment: Unless you pass the `Content-Type: text/plain` header, the browser will default to `text/html`. This causes the XML to be interpreted as HTML. Using `htmlspecialchars` is fine, you can also resort to using _view-source_. `var_dump` also aids you in detecting these cases as you might see `string(20) "foo"`, the other 17 characters must be _invisible_ somehow.